# eclipse won't always show javadoc or open declaration of rxjava2 Observable (erratically)

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, eclipse-jdt, eclipse-oxygen

Eclipse oxygen3 (march 2018).
Ordinary java project, with rxjava jar and sources.
.classpath file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk18"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="rxjava-2.1.12.jar" sourcepath="rxjava-2.1.12-sources.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="reactive-streams-1.0.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="output"/>
</classpath>
```

I can ctrl-click "Observable", and I can see the source.
But if I use something like:

```
static void test1() throws InterruptedException {
    //Flowable.range(0, 1000)
    Observable.range(0, 1000)
        .doOnNext(i -> {
            System.out.println(", r"+i);
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .doOnNext(i -> {
            System.out.println(", w"+i);
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .subscribe( i -> System.out.println(", f"+i));

    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

then there is a number of methods that don't get javadoc hover popup AND are cannot have a ctrl-click open declaration.

The .range(), the 1st doOnNext(), the 1st subscribeOn() and the observeOn() CANNOT be opened and have javadoc but no tooltip poopup for it, and the others do! The 2nd doOnNext(), the 2nd subscribeOn() and the final subscribe() methods do show the javadoc tooltip and can be ctrl-clicked.

This is driving me nuts... What do I have to do with eclipse to fix this insanity? Do you know of an eclipse bug reported for this?

It appears to occur only on rxjava. Of course it's an IDE bug, but I cannot reproduce easily on others libs. I thought it was because "Observable" has too many methods, perhaps it cannot see more than N. But then it does this crap of showing me the javadoc/opendeclaration for the SAME method (like doOnNext()), just because it is somewhere else in the source... WTF?

Comment: Have you opened the types that own those methods to see if they have sources or JavaDoc attached? What have you *tried*? What "SAME" method are you referring to? Be specific.

Comment: I wrote that they have javadoc and I wrote exactly what I did, and which methods. But I edited and made it even clearer now.

Comment: Have you checked for anything relevant reported in the Error Log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably [Eclipse Bug 515758](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=515758), i.e., RxJava seems to contain some signatures which breaks the use case of selecting  / resolving a reference into that library. After resolving failed, the tool doesn't know for which element javadoc should be shown.

Comment: thanks a lot for linking in the bugzilla! However, it doesn't mention that the same methods sometimes work, sometimes don't, depending on source location. This is probably going to turn up as a +/- 1 error on some index variable in the jdt ast model...lol

Comment: Don't worry, with the fix-under-test all invocations in your example have correct hover & ctrl-click behavior (tested against rxjava-2.0.4 in case it matters).

Comment: I don't think this is because of how RxJava is structured but due to the lambdas. I've [reported](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=507936) a similar error 1.5 years ago against 4.6 but apparently it isn't fixed in 4.7.3 either.

Comment: @akarnokd feel free to grab a recent [I-build](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/index.html#4.8_Integration_Builds) to test if the fix for Bug 515758 also covers your case (and yes, you're right lambdas had significant part in this).